# Xubuntu 17.10, BCM4311 installed for WiFi but wlan0 is missing

Tags: xubuntu, broadcom, 17.10

I have a Dell Inspiron 1520 with a Broadcom WiFi card BCM4311.

On the proprietary drivers list I can see that for the wifi card the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package is installed and used, but Network Manager lists only the wired connection and in a terminal I cannot see any WiFi device:

```
user@host$ iwconfig
eth0    no wireless extensions
lo    no wireless extensions
```

Why this behavior if the driver is correctly installed?

Comment: Please consult: https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers  `bcmwl-kernel-source` is not the correct driver.

Comment: Thank you @chili555 for thread suggestion: uninstall `bcmwl-kernel-source`, install `firmware-b43-installer` and reboot solve my issue.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.